# Call a method/property shortcut

Tags: f#

Is there a shorter way to do this?

```
Seq.map (fun x -> x.SomeFunction()) xs
Seq.map (fun x -> x.SomeProperty) xs
```

This clearly doesn't work

```
Seq.map SomeFunction() xs
Seq.map SomeProperty xs
```

Which would allow something like this more simply

```
Seq.map (SomeProperty >> fn1 >> fn2) xs
```

I'm using Seq.map here, but there is nothing special about it. There are many other functions for which this would be nice. I've spent some time looking to see if I missed some syntax sugar somewhere, but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no syntax for turning properties or methods into functions, but it is [a popular feature request](https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5663326-syntax-for-turning-properties-into-functions). Feel free to add your vote there.

The closest thing you can do is to define a function with a static member constraint that allows you to call a method of a specific name and type:

For example, to call `Next : unit -> 'R` you could use:

```
let inline next (value:^T) : 'R = 
  (^T : (member Next : unit -> 'R) value)
```

Now you can write

```
[ new System.Random() ] |> List.map next
```

This is not really very useful (unless you need to do this very often for a specific method or property) and so my preference is to just use explicit function.

Comment: Use "new" not necessarily ;)